# C++ When to use pointer to vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a problem about `pointer` and `standard library` use.

Let's create a new class

```
class Graph
{
    std::vector<Edge> *edge_list;
    //another way is
    //std::vector<Edge> edge_list;
}
```

I already thought two reasons why I use pointer:

1. It's easy to manipulate the memory using `new` and `delete`
2. It can be passed by parameters easily.

However, we can `pass by reference` if we use `vector`.Then Reason 2 doesn't count.

So, Is it true if I am not strict with memory allocation, I don't need to use pointer to `vector` and other `std` container?

Comment: What do you want to happen to `edge_list` if you make a copy of a `Graph`? If both copies should refer to the same vector, you need a pointer.

Comment: But you should probably use a smart pointer, so the vector will be deleted at the proper time.

Comment: `vector` is a tool that manages memory for you so that you don't need `new` and `delete`. Using `new` and `delete` to manage the memory of a tool that manages memory for you so that you don't need `new` and `delete` is almost always as counter productive as it sounds.

Comment: Barmar hints at [The Rule of Three/Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Make sure you understand the linked rules before you make an object that manages a dynamically allocated resource. One of the glories of `std::vector` is it does all the Rule of Three/Five work for you, allowing your class to take advantage of The Rule of Zero.

Comment: To me it's unclear what do you mean by "... if I am not strict with memory allocation ..." ?

Comment: When to use a pointer to a vector: **never**. (Of course, like all absolutes in engineering, this is not always true, but it's very rare that you'll need to do that -- your first instinct should be to use an object directly)

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `std::vector` contains 2 pointers:

- The beginning of the allocated array
- 1 element after the end of the allocated array

Essentially, when you declare a vector it has no space allocated in the heap, but as you add elements this changes.

Note that `std::vector` manages the memory it uses, so there is no need for you to worry about `new` and `delete` (unnecessary complexity). As soon as it goes out of scope, it deallocates its memory (stack and heap).

As you said, a vector can be passed very easily by reference, which works the same way as a pointer for machine code, and it's more clear.